# getKey() returns value instead of ID

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get the ID of a specific child in a Firebase Database.
The database looks like this:

```
Users:

 - id: user1
 - id: user2
 - ...
```

Now I want to return `ID` of each user and I tried it with this;

```
DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        ValueEventListener users = databaseRef.child("Users").child(bundle.getString("User")).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String userID = dataSnapshot.getKey();


                mTextView.setText(userID);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                //error
            }
        });
```

`bundle.getString("User")` is the String that contains the value of which user I want to get the `ID` from.

When I open the app, the text in mTextView just contains the username instead of the ID.

What did I do wrong here?

The app is a ListView in the main activity containing all the users. When the user clicks on a list item a new activity opens. In this activity I want to show the selected user's info but for that i want to get the ID to find the corresponding info in the database with the same ID..

JSON:

```
{
  "Users" : [ null, "Jef", "Peter", "Jean", "Ronny" ]
}
```

Comment: Try to log this `dataSnapshot.getRef().toString()` and post the result. Based on your database structure `bundle.getString("User")` should be the `id` part, right? Also, please export the database as JSON and then post it here.

Comment: @Wilik dataSnapshot.getRef().toString() returns the link to the child in the database and no bundle.getString("User") contains the value like for example "user1" from which I want the ID..

Comment: Nothing is wrong in your code. But by posting the database structure as JSON, we might find what the problem is, you can remove any sensitive information.
By the way, you have the ID already at `bundle.getString("User")`, why are you trying to get the same string by calling `dataSnapshot.getKey()`? If you want to get the value, you should instead call `dataSnapshot.getValue()`

Comment: @Wilik where do I post the JSON file?

Comment: @Wilik No, bundle.getString("User") returns the value, what I want is the ID that Firebase gave to the user..

Comment: just put the content in this question.

Comment: @Willik The JSON is added.. As you can see, bundle.getString("User") contains "Jef" for example.. I want to get the ID of "Jef".

Comment: thanks for posting the JSON file, now I know your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommended for you to read this article [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html)

> arrays are quite handy. But for distributed data, they aren't reliable because they lack a unique, permanent way to access each record.

It means you can't retrieve each index of the array under `Users`. You can retrieve the whole array first (`databaseRef.child("Users").addValueEventListener()`), cast the returned dataSnapshot to an array and then check the value manually or use `contains` method.

What I suggest is to change your database structure to like this

```
{
    "Users" : {
        "Jef" : true,
        "Peter" : true,
        "Jean" : true,
        "Ronny" : true
    }
}
```

With this database structure, you don't need to change the code because it should work already.

**EDIT:** For your case, you can save the other user details in the other node of the database

```
{
    "Users" : {
        "Jef" : true,
        "Peter" : true,
        "Jean" : true,
        "Ronny" : true
    },
    "Users_details" : {
        "Jef" : {
            "city" : "some_city_name",
            "address" : "some_address_name",
            "phone_number" : "some_phone_number"
        },
        "Peter" : {
            "city" : "some_city_name",
            "address" : "some_address_name",
            "phone_number" : "some_phone_number"
        },
        "Jean" : {
            ...
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

- To get the list of usernames, you just need to listen to `Users` node
- Then, when a view in the listview is clicked, send the username as intent extra to the other activity `intent.putExtra("username", username);`
- Finally, in the new activity, listen to `Users_details/<username_from_intent>` to get the user details (phone number, address, etc)

Hope this helps, this structure is definitely better than saving each detail in an array. If you read the first link I provided, this practice should be avoided because you might change the user details.

Comment: But the goal of my app is to get related info from the Firebase Database. All these info's will be stored in different arrays (Users, Adresses, Phone numbers, ...) and the info's that are related get the same ID.. How can I do this with this structure?

Comment: I edited my Database, but now of course the ListView with all my users doesn't work because they are all Booleans.. So now I need to get the ID's in my ListView?

Comment: You are not supposed to store your data like that in Firebase / NoSQL database. I suggest you to watch this playlist [Firebase for SQL Developers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WacqhiI-g_o&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) and read [Structure Your Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data)
If you don't want to change your database structure, read my updated answer @MaartenWeyns

Comment: So I was off there for a day, now I'm back.. Now a better explanation of my goal; I have an app with a list view with all usernames. When I click on a user, a new activity opens where the details of the clicked user are (city, adress, phone number, ...). Those are all stored in the database in different arrays, but with the same ID so I would be able to link them together.. Now that thing is the ting I can't seem to achieve.. @Wilik

Comment: hello there @MaartenWeyns, look at my updated answer